# Confused if not elif not statements conflicting

Tags: python, if-statement, argparse

I am using argparse. I am trying to make it so if these statements aren't used in conjunction I get a message saying "Error: Incompatible arguments."

```
if not args.write == args.write * args.encrypt:
    print("Error: Incompatible arguments.")
    sys.exit()
elif not args.write == args.write * args.encrypt * args.copy:
    print("Error: Incompatible arguments.")
    sys.exit()
else:
    print("The rest of the code..")
```

This is not the expected result...

Using -w -e gives me "Error: Incompatible arguments."
Using -w -e -c executes the code properly.

Why would this be? How can I fix it?

Thank you.

Comment: Don't give us an `argparse` question without either showing the parser definition, or at least printing the `args` Namespace.  You have left us guessing as to the values of these `args` attributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're testing backwards. It's supposed to be legal for only `write` and `encrypt` to be set, but when `not args.write == args.write * args.encrypt` passes, it's moving on to the `elif`, and if `copy` is `0`, then you'll say it's incompatible, even though it passed the first (sufficient) test for validity.

I'm guessing you really want to test:

```
if not (args.write == args.write * args.encrypt or args.write == args.write * args.encrypt * args.copy):
    print("Error: Incompatible arguments.")
    sys.exit()

# Equivalent test if it's more clear to distribute the not:
if args.write != args.write * args.encrypt and args.write != args.write * args.encrypt * args.copy:
    ...
```

Which says that if either test is true, then the arguments were correct, rather than saying if either test is false, then the arguments are incorrect (when passing either test means you have valid arguments).

Mind you, if these are all `True`/`False` switches, doing math is a silly way to test, just test what you're looking for directly:

```
if args.write and not args.encrypt: # Don't test copy at all, because -w requires -e, but doesn't say anything about -c in your described logic
```

Comment: I believe `not (P == P * Q)` is equivalent to `P and not (P and Q)` not just `P and not Q`. This should test `False` if `args.write` is `False`.

Comment: Distributing the `not`, `P and not (P and Q)` is the same as `P and (not P or not Q)`. Since `P` has to be true to evaluate the second clause (if it's false, the `and` short circuits), `not P` is always going to be false when evaluated, so only the value of `not Q` matters, meaning that it's really `P and not Q`; if this were C, the compiler would actually directly convert `P and not (P and Q)` to `P and not Q` for you, but Python isn't smart enough to figure that out, so `P and not (P and Q)` is just wasteful.

Comment: Error on my part, for some reason I had different truth table in mind.

Answer (score 0):

Why not do the more intuitive thing here?

```
if (args.write != args.write * args.encrypt) or (args.write != args.write * args.encrypt * args.copy):
    print("Error: Incompatible arguments.")
    sys.exit()
else:
    print("The rest of the code..")
```

Comment: While intuitive, this is the same logic he has, and it will get the same results.

Comment: I have tried "more intuitive things" before hand.. but it returned the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't the `elif` unnecessary, you seem to say either -w is not set or you must have -e set if -w is set with or without -c, so you just need the first condition, no?

Simplified:

```
if not args.write == args.write * args.encrypt:
    print("Error: Incompatible arguments.")
    sys.exit()
print("The rest of the code..")
```

Just using boolean logic:

```
if args.write and not args.encrypt:
    print("Error: Incompatible arguments.")
    sys.exit(1)
print("The rest of the code..")
```